# How do I call a method from a class in a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

How do I call a method from a class in a ruby gem?

i.e.

> gem install [mindbody](http://rubygems.org/gems/mindbody)

In the gem's [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mindbody/0.1.7/frames), I see various classes. But no guideline on how to call these classes from code.

For example, I'd like to call a method in the `ClassService` class.

Comment: If there aren't any usage docs, try looking at the tests.

Comment: I'm new to RoR, could you please clarify what you mean by looking at the tests? I've done grep and find no reference to mindbody in my app.

Comment: In the gem itself. There won't be any references to it until you use it, or the only references will be where the gem installed to.

Comment: According to gem environment my installation path is /Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ which has bin/ cache/ doc/ gems/ specifications/ I didn't find tests in any of the these folders for the mindbody gem.

Comment: Indeed, the source repo (that you link to, btw) has no meaningful tests. So unless you can find someone using the gem, online examples, etc. you're on your own. Start reading source!

Comment: For anyone finding this question via search, definitely check out the [mindbody-api gem](https://github.com/wingrunr21/mindbody-api) if you are building a Rails app that needs to consume web services from MindBody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MindBody look at root Module Mb.

You can list all types declared using:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mindbody'
Mb.constants
```

It gives you:

`["AppointmentService", "SourceCredentials", "Meta", "StaffService", "Options", "SiteService", "StaffOptions", "Credentials", "ClientService", "ClassService", "SaleService", "Service"]`

After you can call `Mb::ClassService.new` or `include Mb; ClassService.new`

A little bit of metaprogramming for you